The Equation $ax^2+30x−40 >0$ for $x$ -values in $2<x<b$ . Find $a+b$
Not sure if the premise of the question is correct, this came from a math contest last year and I must say that I forgot the exact wording of the question, but nonetheless I'll try to type the question from memory.

The Equation $ax^{2}+30x-40$ is greater than 0 for $x$-values in $2<x<b$. Find $a+b$

My attempt at this question is the following,
We know that $f(x)=ax^{2}+30x-40>0$ which means its first derivative must be positive.
$f'(x)=2ax+30>0 \implies ax>-15$
Here I have to think a bit about the positiveness/negativeness of $a$. If $a>0 \implies \frac{-15}{a}<x$. And if $a<0 \implies x < \frac{-15}{a}$.
Not sure what to do with these informations, any help?

Why do you think $f(x)$ positive means $f$ is an increasing function?

The sign of $f$ tells you nothing about the sign of $f'$ since $(f+C)' = f'$ for any constant $C$

Ah right, I'll take note of that for the future

HINT
Suppose that $a > 0$. I would start with completing squares:
\begin{align*}
ax^{2} + 30x - 40 > 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (a^{2}x^{2} + 30ax) - 40a > 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a^{2}x^{2} + 30ax + 225) - 40a - 225 > 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ax + 15)^{2} - 40a - 225 > 0
\end{align*}
Then study each case $40a + 225 < 0$, $40a + 225 = 0$ and $40a + 225 > 0$ separately.
After so, apply the same reasoning to $a < 0$.
Can you take it from here?

For the question to make sense, it must be "$\cdots$ is greater than $0$ for $x$
-values $\textbf{only}$ in $2<x<b\cdots$".
Otherwise, $(a+b)$ is not a fixed quantity. Assuming that is the case, you can infer that the given function must be a parabola that opens downward and has it's zeroes at $x=2$ and $x=b$. Thus, $f(2)=f(b)=0$ would give you $a=-5$ and $b=4$,  i.e. $a+b=-1$.
